# skhd to run shell script with dynamic argument

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

On macOS, is it possible to use `skhd` to run a shell script containing a case statement with a shortcut such as <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and make the script use the given letter (`a`, or `p` respectively) as the key for the case statement?

Comment: It would seem better to raise an issue on the [skhd Github repository](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) to ask the author

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Create two wrapper scripts mapped to the hotkey which then call the main script with a parameter.

- Modify the main script to accept one parameter to be used in the `case` statement
- Create two additional shell script, let's call them `script_a` and `script_p`.
- Have `script_a` basically run `main_script A` (and `script_p` `main_script P`)
- Use `skhd` to map <kbd>Alt-A</kbd> to `script_a`, <kbd>Alt-P</kbd> to `script_p`.

PS: The expert version of this are two hard links called `script_a` and `script_p`, both pointing to `main_script`, and looking at `$0` within the case statement of the main script.